# Can't send running ec2 instance list from lambda to slack using webhook url

Tags: json, lambda, http-post, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have a **lambda function** which filters out running ec2 instances and stores them in an array, then it is sent as a **payload** to the **slack channel**. The problem is when I run the function it will not send the **list** but the print command will list it out on output.

````
import json
import boto3
import logging
import os
import urllib3
import urllib.parse

#from urlparse import parse_qs
from boto3 import resource

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
region = 'us-east-1'



def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region)
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"
    text = "hi"
    filters = [
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running']
        }
    ]

    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters = filters)

    RunningInstances = []

    for instance in instances:
        RunningInstances.append(instance.id)

    instanceList = json.dumps(RunningInstances)
    
 
                                       #List out running ec2 instances

  
    print(instanceList) 
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
  
   
    r = http.request("POST",
                  "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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",
                 body = json.dumps(instanceList),
                 headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"})
                 ```
````